# JAVA Importing files via ARGS

Tags: java, file, args

I need to import files for input and output by ARGS. This code seems to be too long, can it be more minimalist ?

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(args[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

            File f = new File(args[i]);
            if (f.exists()) {
                System.out.println("file " + args[i] + " exits.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("file " + args[i] + " does not exist");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: There are many ways to write it with less code... But just remember that less code is not always better. Get rid of superfluous code, but leave enough so that you and others can understand it.

Comment: Do you really need to exit early when you find the first file that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Java 8 streams, your code can be rewritten as:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(args[0]);

        Arrays.asList(args).stream().map((s) -> new File(s)).forEach((f) -> {
            if (f.exists()) {
                System.out.println("file " + f + " exits.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("file " + f + " does not exist");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I don't think your focus should be on LOC rather it should be on how well your code is structured and written :)

Comment: Perhaps read what Josh Bloch has to say about `forEach` in the new edition of Effective Java. This is an example of where a plain old loop (or, rather, an enhanced for loop) would be easier.

Comment: Agree, IMO, the code in OP is clearer. That said the question is about reducing the LOC :)

Answer (score -1):

This isn't tested, but it should work.  It uses functional features to get the list of missing files.  Then you can just loop over that if it's length is > 0 and print them all out/exit.

```
List<File> missingFiles = Arrays.asList(args)
    .map(f => new File(f))
    .filter(!f.exists())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Uses Java 8 syntax.

Comment: In what sense do you think it works? This doesn't do the same as OP's code at all. (Not the DV).

Comment: The code quickly shows the op how to filter down to missing files (which clearly is his "feature") with ease in a readable and concise manner.  It can easily be used in his case as he wants it to be.  This isn't a "gimme the final solution to my code site", its a helping site to teach techniques.